# Cannot Demultiplex Stream from Video created by Py OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, codec

I'm trying to use OpenCV to create a video out of individual frames. Although the code runs without error, I cannot play the resulting avi file. When I do, the error I get is `Could not demultiplex stream`.

The stripped down version of the code I'm using to do this is:

```
import caffe
import cv2
import fnmatch
import os

# Get Image List
image_list = fnmatch.filter('./sample/images','*.png')
image_list.sort()

# Create VideoWriter
# codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
# codec = -1
codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')
video = cv2.VideoWriter( './movieT.avi',
                         codec,
                         20,
                         (289, 289))

for img_name in image_list:
    # Load image
    im_path = os.path.join('./sample/images',img_name)
    img = caffe.io.load_image(im_path)

    # Resize image to expected size
    img = caffe.io.resize(img,(289, 289, 3))

    # Write image
    video.write(img)
video.release()
```

I Googled around a bit, and the main errors I see mentioned are ensuring the image sizes match the size expected by the `cv2.VideoWiter` and that I have the right codecs. I resize my images to ensure they are the right size and I tried a few different codecs. I also tried to install standard codecs using some `apt-get install` commands I also found by Googling around:

```
me@balin:~$ sudo apt update
me@balin:~$ sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
me@balin:~$ sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I am currently using:

```
Ubuntu 18.04
Python 2.7.17
cv2.__version__ 4.0.1
```

Comment: check `print(image_list)` because `fnmatch.filter()` works different way - it needs `filename`, not `folder`, as first argument. And it check if filename match patterm - it doesn't get filenames from folder - it doesn't work like `glob.glob('./sample/images/*.png')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem in incorrect use of `fnmatch.filter()` which doesn't get filenames from folder but it is used only to check if filename match pattern.

See example from [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch)

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        print(file)
```

With your code I alwyas get empty list so later it can't add any image to video and I can't display this video.

But you can use `glob.glob()` for this

```
image_list = glob.glob('./sample/images/*.png')
```

This code works for me

```
import cv2
import glob

image_list = glob.glob('./sample/images/*.png')
image_list.sort()
#print(image_list)

codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')
video = cv2.VideoWriter('./movieT.avi', codec, 20, (289, 289))

for img_name in image_list:
    img = cv2.imread(img_name)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (289, 289))
    video.write(img)

video.release()
```